# Session variables are lost after server and/or client-side page redirect

Tags: asp.net, html, redirect, response.redirect

**Setup:**

I have a landing page with a button on it. When the user clicks the button a postback occurs. In the click handler of the button I set a couple of session variables. Then I redirect the user to another page.

**Problem:**

When the other page loads, the SessionID is identical (the same session still exists), however, all the session variables have vanished. I have googled the problem extensively trying all the various solutions (and there are many) but none of them have worked for me.

I have tried:

```
Response.Redirect("NewPage.aspx", false);
```

I have also tried adding a meta refresh tag (dynamically) which side-steps any potential problems related to using Response.Redirect(...).

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=NewPage.aspx" />
```

In both of these cases the redirect succeeds but the session variables no longer exist. I have extensively checked all IIS settings, analyzed the data that is exchanged between browser and server, but all to no avail.

Additionally, two colleagues who work on the same project (with identically configured development machines) do not have this problem!

**Question:**

Is there a rational explanation for this problem or have I in some way insulted or offended my development PC and is it now taking revenge on me?

Comment: That's why we must respect our pc :). What session type do you use ? database or inproc. If there any case that after the redirect your page have a bug and change this session again ? Do you have try to redirect with second parameter true ?

Comment: @Aristos Session type is inproc. I have tried setting the second parameter to true but this did not change a thing.

Comment: Do you have a virus scanner running at all? If it touches anything like the Web.Config it will automatically restart the app but I would imagine this would create a new sessionID

Comment: @KevinMain I have disabled Symantec Endpoint Protection but this did not fix the problem.

Comment: You can try to place them on Database to check if this is the issue. You can also set a break point when the page unload to see if the session variables exist on exit of the page before the redirect

Comment: @Aristos I have checked if the session variables exist when the page unloads and they are all there.

Comment: @SeventhElement Can you check if you post from www.site.com to site.com ? If you do that also the session can lost if you not setup correct the cookie of the session.

Comment: @Aristos I checked that Session.SessionID is the same on the source and target pages. I derive from this that the session itself was never lost. Just the information that is stored as part of the session.

Comment: are you trying to edit/update/delete any directory or files ??

Answer (score 0):

I recall seeing this issue happen when calling response.redirect() during an asynchronous post back.  If you are using an UpdatePanel, try removing it to see if it solves the issue.  If that is the problem, then I believe this has to do with a bug in an old version of the Ajax libraries.  Since you haven't made any mention of version information, I think that this is a fair assumption.

Comment: There are no update panels on the page. There is ScriptManager control on the master page but removing that did not fix the problem.